# Единственное или множественное число существительного?

Tags: грамматика

**«В верхней и нижней панелях (панели?) шкафа предусмотрены места для установки кабельных вводов».** Как верно писать слово «панели» в данном контексте? Во множественном или единственном числе? Или оба варианта возможны? Панелей у шкафа всего две – вверху и внизу, это крыша и пол имеются в виду. То есть одна верхняя и одна нижняя панель в шкафу. Надо говорить о них во множественном или в единственном числе? Спасибо!

Comment: Панель — это дверцы (створки, стенки) — фасадный элемент шкафа, т. е. правильно будет: за панелью, в верхней секции, на верхнем уровне. Горизонтальная плоскость внутри шкафа называется полкой, нижняя — поликом.

Comment: Спасибо! Так у заказчика термины уже определены: пол (панель-пол, днище) они называют "нижняя панель", а крышу (панель-крышу, потолок) они называют "верхняя панель". Потому что поверх "верхней панели" у них ещё и крышу можно прикрутить. Такая особенность. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Здесь гораздо лучше множественное число, тем более что там и дальше множественное – "места".

Comment: Спасибо! Так и будем писать, во мн. числе, грамматически так верно, думаю. Но если в технических описаниях, то, мне кажется, иногда можно бы и в ед. числе в таких случаях(?) Смысл такой, что в шкафу ведь только по одной верхней и нижней панели, а не по несколько. Так как-то мне думается... Спасибо!